# how to hand special character 'SUB' in Informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a source flat file with one column and three rows like below.

```
Column_1  
200
ABC  
->
```

The -> is a special character (or displayed as SUB in NOTEPAD++). In my mapping I'm reading the column_1. I can able to read the row 200 and ABC but not sure how to read the special character ->. In my mapping, I have a Expression and router transformations. I have trgt_1, trgt_2, trgt_3. I need to check if the Column_1 contains any special characters and if yes, then route that row to Target_3. Any help appreciated!

Comment: yes you are right. That is SUB character as i mentioned in my first post. my question how to check that the source flat file contains special character (-> or SUB) and route it to target flat file 'target_3' accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII code for SUB is 26. You may be able to use the Ascii function in an expression transformation to check for the SUB character.